# proof that metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ cannot have counterintuitive property

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose $d$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose induced topology is the same as the euclidean topology and such that $$\left\{w \in \mathbb{R}^2 : d (w,0)=1\right\}$$is nonempty and compact. Assume that for arbitrary $w=\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $d(w,0)=1$ there is $1>t_0^w > 0$ such that $$d\left( t\cdot \begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix} , 0\right)>d\left( s\cdot \begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix} , 0\right)\quad\forall t_0^w>t>s>0.$$Is there a global $t_0>0$, such that $t_0^w > t_0$ for all $w \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $d (w,0)=1$?

Comment: I think there is a problem. $t_0^w$ is not uniquely defined, so the last question makes no sense.

Comment: Is the assumption that for all $w$ there exists a $t_{0}^{w}$, or is it just known that such a $t_{0}^{w}$ exists for some $w$?

Comment: As the OP phrased it, it seems the assumption is: for each $w$, there is some such $t_0^w$.

Comment: To 'build' the set $\{t_0^w:d(w,0)=1\}$ we must choose some suitable $t_0^w$ for each $w$. The question is if that set is bounded. But we don't know if it should be bounded for *every* choice of the $t_0^w$'s or for *some* such a choice.

Comment: @ajotatxe The reason we are getting confused by the OP's question is that using just the Euclidean metric alone one can construct a case with suitable $t_0^w$ where the OP's statement is true and another case with suitable $t_0^w$ where the OP's statement is false. So logically, the OP's statement is neither provable nor disprovable.

Comment: the problem was, that the relation at the end was the wrong side around. I want $t_0^w$ to be bounded below, so the question is wether there is a global $t_0>0$ with $t_0^w >t_0$ for all $w$. Also, to make $t_0^w$ unique for each $w$, we can choose the maximal $t_0^w\le 1$ which still satisfies the condition.
sorry for that and thanks for your interest!
also, I mean that for each $w$ with above assumptions, there is such a $t_0^w$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no positive $t_0$ in general, and there exists a distance function $d$ such that $t_0$ cannot be positive, no matter how the $t_0^w$ are chosen.

Consider the continuous function
$$f(x_1, x_2) := \begin{cases}2 x_2\cdot \max(0, (1-|x_2^2/x_1-1|)) & \text{ if }x_1 \neq 0\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
 on $\mathbb R^2$.

Now use this $f$ to define the metric $d(x,y) := |x_1-y_1| + |x_2-y_2| + |f(x) - f(y)|$. This metric induces the usual euclidean topology on $\mathbb R^2$. This can be seen by the fact that $d(x,y) = d_1((x,f(x)), (y,f(y)))$, where $d_1$ is the taxicab metric on $\mathbb R^3$ and the map $x \mapsto (x,f(x))$ is an embedding of $\mathbb R^2$ into $\mathbb R^3$.

Now consider any $w = (u, v)$ with $d(w,0) = 1$. Then for sufficiently small $t$, $$d(tw, 0) = t|u| + t|v| + 2t\left|v \cdot \max(0, (1-|tv^2/u-1|))\right|$$
$$= t\cdot(|u|+|v|) + \begin{cases}2t^2|v^3/u| & \text{ if } u > 0 \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

which is strictly ascending in $t$. So there does exist a $t^w_0$ as desired.

Fix a choice of all $t^w_0$, and let $t_0$ be the infimum of all $t^w_0$.

However, for every small $\varepsilon > 0$, consider the vector $\tilde w := (\varepsilon, 1)$, and let $w := \frac{1}{1+\varepsilon}\tilde w$.

For sufficently small $\varepsilon$, we have $0 < \varepsilon < 2\varepsilon < 1 < \frac{1}{1+\varepsilon}$.

Then it is true that $d(0, \varepsilon \tilde w) = \varepsilon + \varepsilon^2 + 2\varepsilon$, but $d(0, 2\varepsilon \tilde w) = 2\varepsilon + 2\varepsilon^2 + 0 < d(0, \varepsilon \tilde w)$ and $d(0, w) = 1$.

Choosing $t = 2\varepsilon(1+\varepsilon), s = \varepsilon(1+\varepsilon)$, we just found out that $t > s$ but $d(0, sw) > d(0,tw)$.

Therefore $t_0^w$ must be smaller than $2\varepsilon(1+\varepsilon)$, and $t_0$ must be smaller than that. Unfortunately, when $\varepsilon$ goes to $0$, so does $\varepsilon(1+\varepsilon)$, so $t_0$ cannot be positive. $~~~~\square$

Here's a plot of $f$ for reference:

[image: A plot of f for reference]

Comment: thanks for this great answer! could you explain, why $d$ is a metric? because I don't think showing that it is of the form $d_1 \circ g$ for a metric $d_1$ and a coninuous function $g$ is enough?!

Comment: It's enough if you add the requirement that $g$ is also injective. All the axioms for $d$ then follow directly from the axioms of $d_1$.

Comment: :D yeah you're right. thanks again!

Comment: Note that $g$ doesn't actually need to be continuous, but because $g$ is a homeomorphism from $(\mathbb R^2, d_{eucl})$ to $(g(\mathbb R^2), d_1)$ *and* a homeomorphism (because isomorphism), from $(\mathbb R^2, d)$ to $(g(\mathbb R^2), d_1)$, it follows that $g^{-1} \circ g = id_{\mathbb R^2}$ is a homeomorphism from $(\mathbb R^2, d_{eucl})$ to $(\mathbb R^2, d)$, showing that $d$ and $d_{eucl}$ induce the same topology.